# how to find a command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, search

I have a problem:

I use `lookfor` to find a function or a command in MATLAB, but
Many times `lookfor` gives some results but when I use `help` for learning how to use, I see this statament:

```
No matches found.
```

What is the problem, If  I use the newer version of MATLAB, this problem is solved or not?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is supposed to happen because these two commands are different!

---

The `lookfor` command allows you to search for functions based on a keyword. **It searches through the first line of help text, which is known as the H1 line, for each MATLAB function, and returns the H1 lines containing a specified keyword.** For example, MATLAB does not have a function named inverse. So the response from

```
help inverse
```

is

```
inverse.m not found.
```

But

```
lookfor inverse
```

finds over a dozen matches. Depending on which toolboxes you have installed, you will find entries like

```
INVHILB Inverse Hilbert matrix.
ACOSH   Inverse hyperbolic cosine.
ERFINV  Inverse of the error function.
INV     Matrix inverse.
PINV    Pseudoinverse.
IFFT    Inverse discrete Fourier transform.
IFFT2   Two-dimensional inverse discrete Fourier transform.
ICCEPS  Inverse complex cepstrum.
IDCT    Inverse discrete cosine transform.
```

---

To learn on, check out http://www.thphys.may.ie/CompPhysics/matlab/help/techdoc/basics/getting6.html.